# Server Tomcat v9.0 Server at localhost failed to start,eclipce j2ee

Tags: jakarta-ee

Tomcat server 9.0 not starting in eclipse It showing error "Server Tomcat v9.0 Server at localhost failed to start."I have tried alot of things from changing port to uninstalling tomcat and eclipse then reinstalling it again but nothing changed,thanks in advance for your help.

[image]

few things that may help : [image]

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Serv</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.exemplemvc.ServletControleur</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Serv</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>s</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

> nov. 25, 2018 12:13:58 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log INFOS: Server
>   version:        Apache Tomcat/9.0.13 nov. 25, 2018 12:13:58 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log INFOS: Server
>   built:          Nov 2 2018 14:27:55 UTC nov. 25, 2018 12:13:58 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log INFOS: Server
>   number:         9.0.13.0 nov. 25, 2018 12:13:58 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log INFOS: OS Name: 
>   Windows 10 nov. 25, 2018 12:13:58 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log INFOS: OS
>   Version:            10.0 nov. 25, 2018 12:13:58 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log INFOS:
>   Architecture:          amd64 nov. 25, 2018 12:13:58 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log INFOS: Java
>   Home:             C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_191 nov. 25, 2018
>   12:13:58 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
>   INFOS: JVM Version:           1.8.0_191-b12 nov. 25, 2018 12:13:58 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log INFOS: JVM
>   Vendor:            Oracle Corporation nov. 25, 2018 12:13:58 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log INFOS:
>   CATALINA_BASE:
>   C:\Users\USER\eclipse-workspace.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0
>   nov. 25, 2018 12:13:58 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log INFOS:
>   CATALINA_HOME:         C:\Users\USER\Downloads\apache-tomcat-9.0.13
>   nov. 25, 2018 12:13:58 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log INFOS: Command
>   line argument:
>   -Dcatalina.base=C:\Users\USER\eclipse-workspace.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0
>   nov. 25, 2018 12:13:58 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log INFOS: Command
>   line argument:
>   -Dcatalina.home=C:\Users\USER\Downloads\apache-tomcat-9.0.13 nov. 25, 2018 12:13:58 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
>   INFOS: Command line argument:
>   -Dwtp.deploy=C:\Users\USER\eclipse-workspace.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps
>   nov. 25, 2018 12:13:58 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log INFOS: Command
>   line argument:
>   -Djava.endorsed.dirs=C:\Users\USER\Downloads\apache-tomcat-9.0.13\endorsed
>   nov. 25, 2018 12:13:58 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log INFOS: Command
>   line argument: -Dfile.encoding=MS932 nov. 25, 2018 12:13:58 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent INFOS:
>   Loaded APR based Apache Tomcat Native library [1.2.18] using APR
>   version [1.6.5]. nov. 25, 2018 12:13:58 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent INFOS:
>   APR capabilities: IPv6 [true], sendfile [true], accept filters
>   [false], random [true]. nov. 25, 2018 12:13:58 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent INFOS:
>   APR/OpenSSL configuration: useAprConnector [false], useOpenSSL [true]
>   nov. 25, 2018 12:13:58 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener initializeSSL INFOS:
>   OpenSSL successfully initialized [OpenSSL 1.1.1  11 Sep 2018] nov. 25,
>   2018 12:13:58 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init INFOS:
>   Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"] nov. 25, 2018 12:13:58
>   PM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector INFOS:
>   Using a shared selector for servlet write/read nov. 25, 2018 12:13:58
>   PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init INFOS: Initializing
>   ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"] nov. 25, 2018 12:13:58 PM
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector INFOS:
>   Using a shared selector for servlet write/read nov. 25, 2018 12:13:58
>   PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load INFOS: Initialization
>   processed in 893 ms nov. 25, 2018 12:13:58 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal INFOS:
>   D?marrage du service [Catalina] nov. 25, 2018 12:13:58 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal INFOS: Starting
>   Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/9.0.13 nov. 25, 2018 12:13:59 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal GRAVE: A child
>   container failed during start java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
>   org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component
>   [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/EX1TP3]]
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:951)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:831)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1432)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1422)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)  at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
>     at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:944)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:261)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:422)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:801)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
>     at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:695)    at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:350)   at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:492) Caused
>   by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component
>   [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/EX1TP3]]
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(LifecycleBase.java:441)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:198)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1432)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1422)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)  at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
>     at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:944)
>     ... 21 more Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
>    [s] invalide dans l'association de servlet (servlet
>   mapping)  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.addServletMappingDecoded(StandardContext.java:3136)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.Context.addServletMappingDecoded(Context.java:879)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureContext(ContextConfig.java:1380)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1191)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:769)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:299)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5007)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
>     ... 27 more
>
> nov. 25, 2018 12:13:59 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase
>   startInternal GRAVE: A child container failed during start
>   java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
>   org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed
>   during start  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:951)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:261)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:422)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:801)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
>     at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:695)    at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:350)   at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:492) Caused
>   by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed
>   during start  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:963)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:831)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1432)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1422)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)  at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
>     at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:944)
>     ... 13 more Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
>   org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component
>   [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/EX1TP3]]
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:951)
>     ... 21 more Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed
>   to start component
>   [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/EX1TP3]]
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(LifecycleBase.java:441)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:198)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1432)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1422)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)  at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
>     at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:944)
>     ... 21 more Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
>    [s] invalide dans l'association de servlet (servlet
>   mapping)  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.addServletMappingDecoded(StandardContext.java:3136)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.Context.addServletMappingDecoded(Context.java:879)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureContext(ContextConfig.java:1380)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1191)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:769)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:299)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5007)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
>     ... 27 more
>
> nov. 25, 2018 12:13:59 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
>   GRAVE: The required Server component failed to start so Tomcat is
>   unable to start. org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child
>   container failed during start     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:963)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:261)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:422)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:801)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
>     at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:695)    at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:350)   at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:492) Caused
>   by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
>   org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed
>   during start  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:951)
>     ... 13 more Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A
>   child container failed during start   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:963)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:831)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1432)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1422)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)  at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
>     at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:944)
>     ... 13 more Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
>   org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component
>   [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/EX1TP3]]
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:951)
>     ... 21 more Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed
>   to start component
>   [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/EX1TP3]]
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(LifecycleBase.java:441)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:198)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1432)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1422)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)  at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
>     at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:944)
>     ... 21 more Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
>    [s] invalide dans l'association de servlet (servlet
>   mapping)  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.addServletMappingDecoded(StandardContext.java:3136)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.Context.addServletMappingDecoded(Context.java:879)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureContext(ContextConfig.java:1380)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1191)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:769)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:299)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5007)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
>     ... 27 more
>
> nov. 25, 2018 12:13:59 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
>   INFOS: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"] nov. 25, 2018
>   12:13:59 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause INFOS: Pausing
>   ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"] nov. 25, 2018 12:13:59 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService stopInternal INFOS: Arr?t du
>   service [Catalina] nov. 25, 2018 12:13:59 PM
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy INFOS: Destroying
>   ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"] nov. 25, 2018 12:13:59 PM
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy INFOS: Destroying
>   ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]

Comment: Update your question to include the content of Tomcat's log that shows the error. As it stands your question cannot be answered because of the lack of information.

Comment: Done ,i guess .

Answer (score 1):

For problems like this the first thing to examine is the Tomcat log. The root cause is reported near the bottom of the extract you added:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: [s] invalide dans l'association de servlet (servlet mapping)
```

That message tells you:

- There is a problem with the servlet mapping, which in your case is being done in your **web.xml** file.
- The problem relates to the use of `s` as a mapping since the message states `[s] invalide...`.

Tomcat would not start because of that issue. This is also reported in the log:

```
The required Server component failed to start so Tomcat is unable to start.
```

In **web.xml** the URL pattern is specified as `<url-pattern>s</url-pattern>`, which is invalid.

It's worth noting that if you use Eclipse's servlet wizard to create a servlet, and attempt to specify a URL pattern of **`s`** in **URL Mappings** you get a very helpful error message:

```
"s" is unresolvable URL pattern. URL patterns should start with "/" or "*.".
```

[image: InvalidUrlPattern]

To fix the problem just change the URL pattern to start with a forward slash:

```
 <url-pattern>/s</url-pattern>
```

Full details are in the Servlet Specification Version 4.0. See Chapter 12 titled [*Mapping Requests to Servlets*](https://javaee.github.io/servlet-spec/downloads/servlet-4.0/servlet-4_0_FINAL.pdf#G16.999461), and in particular section 12.2: *"Specification of Mappings"*.